# How do I add bots to a Discord server without permission?

Tags: discord, bots

I have a bot ready for work. I have a question that I want my bot to get in a server I do not own or the server for which I don't have admin permission?
Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't add a bot to a server if you don't have permissions in that server.

Comment: If I have invitation link of that server. Is that link of any use for this particular task?

Comment: No, you need to have ADMINISTRATOR permission in the server you are trying to add a bot into.

Comment: Ok got it.
Thank You.